# Counting frequencies of frequencies

Tags: count, stata

I was wondering if there was a way to determine the number of times an ID appears in Stata. I have included an example below:

```
    ID
1. 2652333
2. 9897222
3. 2652333
4. 0011003
5. 9897222
6. 2652333
```

In the above example the first ID (2652333) has 3 records, the second ID (9897222) had 2 records and the 4th ID (0011003) has 1 record. The dataset has millions of records, so the `tabulate` command will not work.

I would like to produce a table similar to the one below:

```
    Count    |     Freq 
1.  1        |    1000000 (i.e. 1 million IDs only had one record)
2.  2        |      50000 (i.e. 50000 IDs had two records)
3.  3        |      10000 (i.e. 10000 IDs had 3 records)
4.  4        |       1000 (i.e. 1000 IDs had 4 records)
5.  5        |        500 (i.e. 500 IDs had 5 records)
6.  6        |         60 (i.e. 60 IDs had 6 records)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contract` twice to solve this:

```
contract ID, freq(Count)
contract Count, freq(Freq)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without destroying the data.

```
clear 
input ID 
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
end 

bysort ID : gen count = _N 
egen tag = tag(ID)

tab count if tag 

      count |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          1 |          1       25.00       25.00
          2 |          1       25.00       50.00
          3 |          1       25.00       75.00
          4 |          1       25.00      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |          4      100.00
```

The constraint on `tabulate` runs into thousands of rows: see `help limits` in your Stata. If that really bites, you would be producing a table no-one is likely to want to read, but `groups` from the *Stata Journal* would help.